# How to add a vertical scrollbar to a ext gridpanel when the grid reaches certain height?

Tags: extjs, scrollbar, ext.net, gridpanel

I have a popup window that has a tab panel and 'save' button below it. One of the tab contains a gridpanel and 'Add New Row' button. Initially, the gridpanel has no rows. How can I display a vertical scrollbar when gridpanel's height reaches certain pixel values, or certain no. of rows are added?
The code looks like this:

```
<ext:Window ID="Window1" runat="server" Height="600px" Width="400px" Title="Popup Window">
        <Items>
            <ext:TabPanel ID="tabMain" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="300px">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Panel ID="pnlItem" runat="server" Title="Item">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Container runat="server">
                                <Content>
                                    <div>
                                        ...
                                        ...
                                    </div>
                                </Content>
                            </ext:Container>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                    <ext:Panel ID="pnlQuantities" runat="server" Title="Quantities">
                        <Items>
                            <ext:Container runat="server">
                                <Content>
                                    <div>
                                        Grid Below:
                                    </div>
                                    <div>
                                        <ext:GridPanel ID="gridQuantities" runat="server" Width="400px" Height="200px" Header="false">
                                            <Store>
                                            ..........
                                            ..........
                                            </Store>
                                        </ext:GridPanel>
                                        <ext:Button ID="btnAddRow" runat="server" Text="Add New Row" Icon="Add">
                                            <Listeners>
                                                <Click Fn="addNewRow" />
                                            </Listeners>
                                        </ext:Button>
                                    </div>
                                </Content>
                            </ext:Container>
                        </Items>
                    </ext:Panel>
                </Items>
            </ext:TabPanel>            
            <ext:Container runat="server">
                <Items>
                    <ext:Button ID="btnSave" runat="server" Text="Save" Icon="Disk"></ext:Button>
                </Items>
            </ext:Container>
        </Items>
    </ext:Window>
```

How can I do this please help.

Comment: Set the config autoScroll : true, and the scrollbars are created just when needed. Like this you don't have to care about them.

Comment: You scored 3 points for that comment. Probably, it is good to post it as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks [Lorenz Meyer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1951708/lorenz-meyer). I just had to add *AutoScroll: true* to my GridPanel. And also I set *MaxHeight* to 200 so whenever the grid reaches 200px height, the vertical scrollbar appears.

```
<ext:GridPanel ID="gridQuantities" runat="server" Width="400px" MaxHeight="200" Header="false" AutoScroll="true">
                                            <Store>
                                            ..........
                                            ..........
                                            </Store>
                                        </ext:GridPanel>
```